# How to enable likes on a list with pnpjs or rest api?

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-rest-api, pnpjs

I need to create a list programmatically from SPFX app.
Creating the list is no problem, with pnpjs like so:
sp.web.lists.add("Ideas","Ideas", 100, true);
works great,
but I need to enable likes on this list.
I assume it is passed in the addtionalSettings param, but not having much luck :(

Does anyone know how to enable likes for a list with either PNPjs or the Rest API?

Thank you!
Powell

Comment: Are you trying to enable SharePoint default ratings/likes feature in the list?

Comment: @GaneshSanap yes I am trying to enable that programmatically